# php: about parsing and interpreting process

Tags: php

I always see  `parse` or `compile` in tech articles. So I want to know how PHP works . I found out PHP is Interpreted language, not compiled. I googled online about `parse`, `Interpret` and `compile`, but still not that clear on the whole process. Below is an example PHP code:

```
<?php
$str1="Hello world!";
$str2="What a nice day!";
echo $str1 . " " . $str2;
?>
```

Output:

```
Hello world! What a nice day!
```

Can anyone explain the whole process(parse, interpret...) from source code to the output? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very high level and not necessarily complete overview of the process:

1. The source code is *tokenized*, i.e. it is broken down into individual parts and these parts are "classified". `$str1` is a variable, `=` is an operator, `"Hello world!"` is a string literal, `;` is a statement terminator etc.
2. The tokens are transformed into an [*abstract syntax tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), i.e. the tokens are "grouped by meaning". Something like *we have an **expression** with the `=` **assignment operator** whose **first operand** is `$str1` and whose **second operand** is the string literal `"Hello world!"`.*

   These two steps complete the *parsing*.
3. The individual parts in the syntax tree are translated into low-level machine instructions, e.g. *reserve some memory to store "Hello world!" and create a symbol `$str1` to reference it*.

   That description is still pretty high level for "machine instructions" BTW and I just use it here to keep it simple.

   This is basically the *compilation* step.
4. The instructions are executed.

The distinction between "interpreted" languages and "compiled" languages are somewhat arbitrary. Any language needs to be *parsed* and then translated into machine instructions, which is basically *compilation*. "Real" compiled languages must be compiled into a binary executable first which is then manually executed. PHP basically does both in one go, but then throws the executable code away. That's essentially what *interpreted* code is; it's parsed and compiled on the fly right from the source. There are *byte code caches* for PHP which cache the machine code, not requiring PHP to re-compile the same code over and over.

"Real" compilers also serve other purposes: they can often detect basic or even pretty complex problems during compilation by analyzing the code and then refuse to compile it; since PHP is winging it as it goes along it cannot catch these kinds of problems during compilation and they will crop up while code is already executing, which requires a different kind of error handling philosophy than compiled languages do. "Real" compilers can also spend more time on optimizing code and potentially make it execute faster; since PHP does it on the fly it doesn't spend much if any time on optimizing code, since this would make it even slower.

BTW, PHP as a *language* is neither interpreted nor compiled. It's just a language. The *standard, official PHP runtime environment* is what's interpreting the language. There are also *PHP compilers*, most famously Facebook's HipHop, which compile PHP code into executable binaries.